# Fill calendar from controller

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar

Trying to fill FullCalender Timeline view with events from a controller

Using EJS I can display the calendar and add events manually. Eventually, I will be fetching events from MongoDB via a controller.

```
// the controller
exports.getCalendar = async (req, res, next) => {
  //const meetings = await Meeting.find();
  const current_events = [
    {
      id: '1',
      resourceId: 'MR2',
      title: 'Meeting CEO',
      start: '2019-08-05T11:00:00',
      end: '2019-08-05T12:15:00'
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      resourceId: 'MR2',
      title: 'Meeting CEO',
      start: '2019-08-05T13:00:00',
      end: '2019-08-05T13:15:00'
    }
  ]
  res.render('calendar', {
    events: current_events,
  });
}

// the router
const express = require('express');
const calendar = require('../controllers/calendar');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', calendar.getCalendar);

module.exports = router;

// app.js
const calendar = require('./routes/calendar');
app.use('/api/calendar', calendar);

// calendar script
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 .....
  events: events, //?????? page just hangs
 .........
// console.log of events
    [ { id: '1',
    resourceId: 'MR2',
    title: 'Meeting CEO',
    start: '2019-08-06T11:00:00',
    end: '2019-08-06T12:15:00' },
  { id: '1',
    resourceId: 'MR2',
    title: 'Meeting CEO',
    start: '2019-08-06T13:00:00',
    end: '2019-08-06T13:15:00' } ]
```

in the HTML page I added an EJS line to see what events had.

```
 <body>
      <div id=calendar></div>
      <p><%= events %></p>
    </body>
```

this gives [object Object],[object Object]

Adding the events as an array manually in the calendar script works fine but I would like to display what is exported from the controller, "events". It just hangs. Any pointers would be very greatful.

Comment: "just hangs"...are you sure? Browser code generally doesn't do that. Does your browser UI lock up entirely, or not? More importantly, do you get any errors in the browser's Console? It strikes me that `events` probably isn't defined on the client-side here. I expect you ought to be setting a URL to your controller there, e.g. `events: "http://www.example.com/yourroute"` or something. Also, be careful to ensure your controller renders a plain array of events which fullCalendar can understand, not any kind of object in which the array is wrapped up.

Comment: Just hangs was probably an ill-use of words. The calendar doesn't appear. Removing "events: events," from the calendar script and adding them manually the calendar appears again with the events. Checked the exported "events" from the controller and it is an array. So it is the events I am trying to pass that is causing the problem I suppose. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the console for errors as I suggested? Can you show the actual final event data as it is appearing in the browser?

Comment: P.s. not sure what you mean the "exported" events from the controller? Server side and client-side JavaScript run in separate contexts and cannot talk to each other except by means of HTTP requests. You can't just refer to a server variable in your client side code and expect it to exist

Comment: I have edited my question to include what is logged to the console and what appears in an EJS tag. I suppose that the  [object Object],[object Object] is the problem.

Comment: `[object Object],[object Object]` is what you get if you try to render a complex object/array into the page without accessing the individual members. The browser has no idea how you wanted it to be displayed.

Comment: Now if you wrote `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 .....
  events: <% events %>` into your calendar code, you might get somewhere, because that will inject the **server-side** events variable into the **client-side** fullCalendar code (using EJS syntax - I think, although I know nothing about EJS, just about web apps in general). Do you understand the difference between client-side and server-side script, as I mentioned previously? Nothing you've written so far suggests that you've properly appreciated the difference, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do understand the difference although I am still learning and using this project as a learning exercise while I learn with Udemy. I must admit I am struggling to understand how to inject the data from server-side to the client-side script and vice versa.

Comment: Well did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I think it should probably be `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ..... events: <%= events %>` actually, I made a typo before

Comment: Yes, I did try thanks but it doesn't work. Looked through the docs again and tried using json feed through a URL and it works. Just modified the controller and router and added '/events/' to the events: . Many thanks

Comment: Cool, that was my first suggestion if you recall :-). It's a much better way to do it

Comment: Can you show your final working code @CliveJ so that future readers can see what you mean and where you put the `'/events/'` that you added?

Answer (score 0):

Yes jessi, following the information in the document [calendar, events as JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) I got the data from a mongo database

```
// events from the database
exports.eventsJSON = async (req, res, next) => {
  const eventsFromDB = await Meeting.find();
  res.json(eventsFromDB);
}
```

I then routed it to a URL say /eventsJSONdata and then added

```
events: '/eventsJSONdata/',
```

in the  calendar script.
Hope this helps.